# Seeding Faker Factory Model for many-to-many relations

Tags: php, laravel, factory, seed, faker

I know it's some dump mistake, but i can't locate it for a while. I have table Meals and table Ingredient with relation many-to-many. Want to input some fake data and create ingredient_meal table. I post some code below but when i go for db:seed --class=MealSeeder i get this error

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'title' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `meals` 
(`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2020-05-29 16:26:55, 2020-05-29 16:26:55))

guessing that this factory isn't working right but can't find solution anywhere, i could pass this issue by putting nullable() in migration and updateing my data but that don't seems me right. Thanks in advance for help!

MealFactory.php

```
    $factory->define(App\Meal::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'title' => $faker->realText($maxNbChars = 10),
        'description' => $faker->realText($maxNbChars = 20),
    ];
});

   $factory->define(App\Ingredient::class, function (Faker $faker) {
        static $id = 1;
        return [
            'title' => $faker->realText($faker->numberBetween(10,15)),
            'slug' => $id++, //$faker->unique()->numberBetween(1,20),
        ];
    });
```

Model Meal.php

```
 protected $fillable = ['title','description'];

    public function ingredients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Ingredient');
    }
```

Model Ingredient.php

```
protected $fillable = ['title'];

public function meals()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Meal');
}
```

Meal migration

```
Schema::create('meals', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->string('status')->default('created');
            $table->string('category')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            //$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

MealSeeder.php

```
factory(App\Meal::class, 10)->create()->each(function ($meals) {
    $meals->ingredients()->save(factory(App\Ingredient::class)->make());
});


factory(App\Ingredient::class, 10)->create()->each(function ($ingredients) {
    $ingredients->meals()->save(factory(App\Meal::class)->make());
});

// Get all the ingredients attaching up to 3 random ingredient to each meal
$ingredients = App\Ingredient::all();

// Populate the pivot table
App\Meal::all()->each(function ($meal) use ($ingredients) { 
    $meal->ingredients()->attach(
        $ingredients->random(rand(1, 3))->pluck('id')->toArray()
    ); 
});
```

EDIT:
I moved on, didn't found right solution. I set in migrations, nullable() propethy for 'title' and 'description' attributes. Run seeder and than fill out all null data trought DB::update. It look so ugly now :(

Comment: please make sure you had: use Faker\Generator as Faker; in your file

Comment: OMR tnx for answer but that's not it, i have that

Comment: What line does fail?

Comment: i think in MealSeeder 1st line, my defined factory model is not creating 'title' and 'description' atributes, and then when i want insert in table i get error cuz i am inserting NULL for 'title'

Comment: you may have two MealFactory.php

Comment: No i dont have two :/
https://github.com/matejmalcic/Jela-Svijeta